# Overriding isBinaryContent() method in CXF LoggingOutInterceptor

Tags: java, logging, cxf, interceptor, binary-data

I need to extend the Content Types CXF uses to check for binary data, and came across this answer:
[Stop Apache CXF logging binary data of MultipartBody attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214049/stop-apache-cxf-logging-binary-data-of-multipartbody-attachments)

However, when I try to implement the override of `isBinaryData()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean isBinaryContent(String contentType) {
    return contentType != null && BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES.contains(contentType) || "myContentType".equals(contentType);
}
```

I get an error accessing `BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES`:

> The field AbstractLoggingInterceptor.BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES is not
>   visible

In the CXF implementation, this `BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES` is implemented through a static block as shown in the question referenced at the start.  Do I simply just re-declare this List:

```
private static final List<String> BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES;

static {
    BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES = new ArrayList<String>();
    BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES.add("application/octet-stream");
    BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES.add("image/png");
    BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES.add("image/jpeg");
    BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES.add("image/gif");
}
```

If so, I could just add another entry into the List with my required content type.

Comment: Can we know the reason to extend the Content Types? Are existing types not covering yours?

Answer (score 0):

The field BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES is private and is not accessible from subclasses. The answer in the linked question may have been from an earlier version of CXF, where the list were not private.

As you say you can redeclare the list with your content type also in it. You can also append your logic to the existing logic in the parent implementation:

```
@Override
protected boolean isBinaryContent(String type)
{
    return super.isBinaryContent(type) || "myContentType".equals(type);
}
```

If future versions of CXF alters the BINARY_CONTENT_MEDIA_TYPES list, this implementation automatically inherit those changes. While if the list is copied, then you manually have to change your implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to re-declare a final variable?

Comment: Yes, since it is private. But you may of course name the list declared in the subclass whatever you want.